# Selecting Elements from a 'special' listbox with Selenium in Java

Tags: java, c#, selenium, listbox

So i have the following HTML Code of a listbox here:

```
<div role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectEl docssharedWizSelectPaperselectRoot freebirdFormviewerViewItemsSelectSelect freebirdThemedSelectDarkerDisabled" jscontroller="YwHGTd" jsaction="click:cOuCgd(LgbsSe); keydown:I481le; keypress:Kr2w4b; mousedown:UX7yZ(LgbsSe),npT2md(preventDefault=true); mouseup:lbsD7e(LgbsSe); mouseleave:JywGue; touchstart:p6p2H(LgbsSe); touchmove:FwuNnf; touchend:yfqBxc(LgbsSe|preventMouseEvents=true|preventDefault=true); touchcancel:JMtRjd(LgbsSe); focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e;b5SvAb:TvD9Pc;" jsshadow="" jsname="W85ice" aria-describedby="i.desc.709120473 i.err.709120473" aria-labelledby="i73">
    <div jsname="LgbsSe" role="presentation">
        <div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectOptionList" jsname="d9BH4c" role="presentation">
            <div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectOption freebirdThemedSelectOptionDarkerDisabled exportOption isSelected isPlaceholder" jsname="wQNmvb" jsaction="" data-value="" aria-selected="true" role="option" tabindex="0">
                <div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectRipple exportInk" jsname="ksKsZd"></div>
                <content class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectContent exportContent">Auswählen</content>
            </div>
            <div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectOptionSeparator" role="presentation"></div>
            <div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectOption freebirdThemedSelectOptionDarkerDisabled exportOption" jsname="wQNmvb" jsaction="" data-value="140 cm" aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectRipple exportInk" jsname="ksKsZd"></div>
                <content class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectContent exportContent">140 cm</content>
            </div>
            <div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectOption freebirdThemedSelectOptionDarkerDisabled exportOption" jsname="wQNmvb" jsaction="" data-value="141 cm" aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectRipple exportInk" jsname="ksKsZd"></div>
                <content class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectContent exportContent">141 cm</content>
            </div>
            <div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectOption freebirdThemedSelectOptionDarkerDisabled exportOption" jsname="wQNmvb" jsaction="" data-value="142 cm" aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectRipple exportInk" jsname="ksKsZd"></div>
                <content class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectContent exportContent">142 cm</content>
            </div>
            <div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectOption freebirdThemedSelectOptionDarkerDisabled exportOption" jsname="wQNmvb" jsaction="" data-value="143 cm" aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectRipple exportInk" jsname="ksKsZd"></div>
                <content class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectContent exportContent">143 cm</content>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectDropDown exportDropDown" role="presentation"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="exportSelectPopup quantumWizMenuPaperselectPopup" jsaction="click:dPTK6c(wQNmvb); mousedown:uYU8jb(wQNmvb); mouseup:LVEdXd(wQNmvb); mouseover:nfXz1e(wQNmvb); touchstart:Rh2fre(wQNmvb); touchmove:hvFWtf(wQNmvb); touchend:MkF9r(wQNmvb|preventMouseEvents=true)" role="presentation" jsname="V68bde" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
```

I am writing an program which has to select an element of this listbox automatically in java (like "140 cm", "141 cm" like you see in the code etc...). I tried to access the listbox itself with the following code:

```
WebElement checkBox = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[aria-labelledby*=i73]"));
CheckBox.click();
```

It worked but now i have to select somehow an element of this listbox. I tried it with the 'Select'-Command, which did not work:

```
Select listbox = new Select(checkBox);
listbox.selectByVisibleText("140 cm");
```

I also tried it with clicking on the specific div with the '140 cm' text and waiting for its clickability. But I get a timeout exception because it failed to wait for the element to be clickable.

```
WebElement boxElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[data-value*='140']"));
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
boxElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div[data-value*='140']")));
boxElement.click();
```

I am desperate and do not know what to do. Can any of you guys help me? I am thankfully for every answer!
**greetings**

Comment: Try clicking the main listbox element to make it expand, then click on the child element, see how the aria-expanded property is false on the main div with role listbox

Comment: I did it with like shown in my question: `WebElement checkBox = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[aria-labelledby*=i73]"));
CheckBox.click();`

Comment: Ok, and what happened then?

Comment: The listbox expanded, but if i tried to access one of the listbox elements i got an exception that it was not available. If i waited with a command for the clickability of the element i got a timeout exception.

Comment: I used to do automated testing, so I'm going to take a shot in the dark here, but I bet the listbox element is losing its reference after it is clicked, and that is why its children are innaccesible. After you do the click on the listbox and it expands, then find it again, then search it for the child element you want and try clicking it.